# post_execution hook for a DAG in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Finding a way to execute a piece code after a specific DAG completes (success or failure, regardless)

Looking around the source code, I was able to extend BaseOperator and define a post_execution hook for Operators. Is there something similar for a DAG?

Edit:
My end goal is to publish the status of the DAG to a SQS queue.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator): Take an operator you need to execute your piece of code and make sure that it is the final operator in your DAG, then set the `trigger_rule` to `'all_done'`.

This way, the operator will be executed independently of the success state of the previous operators.

Comment: that sounds like a way. I think I should rephrase my question. Editing the question. My end goal is to publish the status of the DAG, so if I have an Operator connected to all tasks, I still cannot capture the status of the DAG as it will always be 'running' at that point in time.

Comment: @ansh.gandhi What do you mean by status. If the post execute hook of the final operator in your dag is run than it means that the dag run has effectively completed. You can add post execute hooks to the intermediate operators too to report on progress of a dag run.

Comment: post_execution hooks for each Operator will give me the status (success/failed) of each Operator. The post_execute hook for final Operator will only run when all dependent Operators complete (regardless, success or failure). But I can't figure out how do I get the status (success/failed) of the DAG after it is complete/done, so that I can publish DAG status to SQS.
By status I mean - success or failure.

Comment: By default, if at least one of the operators fails then all its downstream operators and the complete dag will fail. If you create a final operator and you see that it fails then you can conclude that the whole dag failed. The status of the final operator is the status of the whole dag.